# optimization of a windows batch file arcade game

Tags: windows, batch-file, optimization

I made a batch file game, and it works, but it is choppy and ugly. I already know about threading, but I don't want to implement that in my first version. I am hoping to have the optimization down before I start doing more advanced things with this game. my question is this: What optimizations can I make to this game, so that it will 1. not be choppy and 2. not be quite so annoying in the display. any ideas or comments about how to make it faster clearer or take less memory are welcome, however, please do not post answers like: "don't use batch" "rewrite it in (insert language here)" "do this part with vb-script" etc... as they are not helpful, nor do they answer the question. any and all non batch hating criticism is welcomed.

here is the code:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
color 0a
mode con lines=35 cols=50
cls
set instructions=use a and d to move left and right, w to fire. use q to quit and p to pause.
set height=30
set length=         
set screen=50
set swidth=20
set amo=8
set lives=3
set 1=0
set 2=1
set 3=2
set 4=3
set 5=4
set 6=0
set 7=1
set 8=2
set 9=3
set 10=4

echo. What quality would you like?
echo.   1. fast, but the graphics suck!
echo.   2. medium both ways.
echo.   3. slow, but the graphics are better!
choice /n /c:123
set firequal=%errorlevel%00
cls
echo %instructions%
echo.
pause
cls

::main
:controls
cls
if %height% EQU 2 goto gameover
if %lives% LSS 1 goto gameover
cls
set /a shouldbomb+=1
set /a whenbomb=shouldbomb%%15
if %whenbomb% == 9 call :bomb
if '%ret%'=='1' exit /b
set ret=
cls
set alive=
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do if defined %%i set alive=true
if not defined alive goto win
cls
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
      if defined %%i (
     set /p a=[_]  <nul
      ) else (
     set /p a=...  <nul
      )
)
echo.
for /l %%i in (6,1,10) do (
      if defined %%i (
     set /p a=[_]  <nul
      ) else (
     set /p a=...  <nul
      )
)
for /l %%a in (1,1,%height%) do echo.
echo %length%[]
echo.
for /l %%i in (1,1,%amo%) do set /p a=^|<nul
echo.
choice /c adwqp0 /n /t 1 /d 0
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :left
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :right
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto :fire
if %errorlevel% equ 4 (cls&exit /b)
if %errorlevel% equ 5 pause&goto controls
if %errorlevel% equ 6 goto :inactive
goto controls

::move player left
:left
if '!length!' NEQ '' set length=!length:~0,-1!
goto controls

::move player right
:right
call :strlen shiplen length
if %shiplen% GTR %swidth% goto controls
set length=%length% 
goto controls

::fire a shot upwards
:fire
if '!amo!' LSS '1' goto controls
cls
set /a amo-=1
for /l %%i in (%height%,-1,2) do (
   cls
   for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
     if defined %%i (
        set /p a=[_]  <nul
     ) else (
        set /p a=...  <nul
     )
   )
   echo.
   for /l %%i in (6,1,10) do (
     if defined %%i (
        set /p a=[_]  <nul
     ) else (
        set /p a=...  <nul
     )
   )
   for /l %%j in (1,1,%%i) do echo.
   echo %length% ^
   set /a ship=height-%%i-1
   for /l %%b in (1,1,!ship!) do echo.
   echo %length%[]
   echo.
   for /l %%i in (1,1,%amo%) do set /p a=^|<nul
   echo.
   for /l %%a in (1,1,%firequal%) do call >nul 2>&1
)
call :checkshot
set /a shouldbomb+=1
set /a whenbomb=shouldbomb%%2
if %whenbomb% == 0 call :bomb
goto controls

:inactive
if %amo% LSS 10 set /a amo+=1
if !height! NEQ 2 set /a height-=1
call :bomb
goto controls

:bomb
:btop
set bombx=
for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do (
   if defined %%a (
     set /a randomnum=%random%%%5
     if '!%%a!'=='%randomnum%' (
        set /a "bombx=5*(!%%a!)"
     )
      )
   )
)
if not defined bombx goto btop
cls
set bomb= 
for /l %%b in (1,1,!bombx!) do (
      set bomb=!bomb! 
)
set /a bombh=height-1
for /l %%c in (1,1,!bombh!) do (
   cls
   for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
     if defined %%i (
        set /p a=[_]  <nul
     ) else (
        set /p a=...  <nul
     )
   )
   echo.
   for /l %%i in (6,1,10) do (
     if defined %%i (
        set /p a=[_]  <nul
     ) else (
        set /p a=...  <nul
     )
   )
   for /l %%b in (1,1,%%c) do echo.
   echo !bomb!x
   set /a ship=height-%%c-1
   for /l %%b in (1,1,!ship!) do echo.
   echo %length%[]
   echo.
   for /l %%i in (1,1,%amo%) do set /p a=^|<nul
   echo.
   for /l %%a in (1,1,%firequal%) do call >nul 2>&1
)
if "%bomb%"   == "%length%"   call :looselife
if "%bomb% "  == "%length%"   call :looselife
if "%bomb%"   == "%length% "  call :looselife
if "%bomb%  " == "%length%"   call :looselife
if "%bomb%"   == "%length%  " call :looselife
exit /b

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "s=!s:~%%P!"
    )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)

:checkshot
call :strlen slen length
for /l %%i in (0,5,20) do (
   if '!slen!' == '%%i' (
      set /a hit=%%i
      set /a hit=hit/5+1
      set /a hit2=hit+5
      if not defined !hit2! set !hit!=
      if defined !hit2! set !hit2!=
   )
)
exit /b

:looselife
set /a lives-=1
set length=         
set 1=0
set 2=1
set 3=2
set 4=3
set 5=4
if %lives% GTR 1 timeout /nobreak 1 >nul 2>&1
exit /b

:win
cls
echo YOU WIN^!^!^!^!
echo.
echo GOOD JOB^!^!^!
echo.
pause
cls
exit /b

:gameover
cls
echo YOU LOOSE.
echo.
echo PLEASE TRY AGAIN.
echo.
pause
cls
set ret=1
```

thank you in advance for any help.

P.S. I am writing this game to convince a friend to learn something besides html, and while batch isn't the best, he uses windows, and he will only do something simple for now. He is twelve, so I think batch is best option.

Comment: You are pushing "batch files" to the absolute limits here, so I don't believe it can be made any faster or prettier. I'd give you a point for effort, but .. as such, it's not really a *good* example for your friend. A 12-yr-old would be more attracted to a *simple* programming language that leads to a pretty game. There must be IDEs for that, certainly on Windows.

Comment: except that i offered JavaScript, and he turned me down, i offered batch and he said that no-one thinks its useful, so why should he learn it. if i can prove its useful, he might learn it. and these are not the limits. view this: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4741 .also, I'm only thirteen and i started with batch when i was 12, and i now love programming, so i think(hope) he could have the same result. mainly i just want to get him excited about something, since he is really depressed. he has a very amazing brain, but he doesn't see that for himself.

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741  <-- show your friend this snake game.  It works very well.

Comment: @foxidrive I'm sorry, but as you see in my previous comment, i already knew about that. his response was(approximate quote): "yah, but that guy abviously spent FOREVER working on it, and was a pro. i dont want to learn something that I'm not going to be able to use until I've been using it FOREVER, and have it take me FOREVER, so what is the use of learning it at all?" i am certain you see my dilema. he thinks of me as a sucky programer however, so if i can do it, then he will realize that he can too, get interested, and then go all out, like he always does when he gets interested. cont.

Comment: if you cant see any optimizations to this one, can you suggest something that wouldn't look crappy to a twelve year old? and that i can have ready to show him by the 9th? (hes coming over on the 9th) i would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Sorry for not seeing your previous link.  IMO the beauty of batch is that you can solve file system, and file conversion and manipulation problems, with very little development and can press all the command line tools into service to solve your problems.  I'm currently working with a tool called `MP3WRAP` that merges MP3 files, and with a couple of 5 minute batch files it processes my audio books into one MP3 file per book.  Try writing an application yourself from scratch to do that and I am sure it would take several days.

Comment: i agree, in real application, batch is good really only for filesystem manipulation, and running commands all at once, dynamically. the reason i use batch for other things, is because it makes me think about the problem, not the billion different things that i need to do and learn to make it happen in another language. while it is not as efficient, it is more fun. i can program what i think, not what your meant to do. cause in reality, batch was never meant to do anything you didnt list. that means it only has a few commands that can make anything else happen. you combine them the right cont.

Comment: way, and you can make most things. it may be slow and ugly, but it is more fun for me, and it is the way i think. i am currently trying to see if i can make a and or not type thing, so that i can say make a text file that contains some logic, and it will be run by the batch like the logic was actual hardware gates. it means i have to really learn how the hardware works, so i can re implement it. of course, it is just for fun, and not really useful.

Comment: If your friend likes html, and you want to attract him to something written in Batch, I suggest you to show him my 
[TextToHtml.bat conversion program](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5016). I think this program have something interesting for you both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely improve things considerably. I know, because I have already produced a very smooth and playable version of [SNAKE using pure Windows batch](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741)! Give it a try - I think you will be surprised and impressed with what musty old batch can do :-)

Of course the link has the code, but it also has pointers on some of the techniques I used to make the came perform so well. Read the entire first post carefully, and read the remainder of the thread for some additional important developments.

Optimization is a large topic. Rather than repeat all the information here, I will simply summarize. Follow the link for more details.

1) Minimize GOTO and CALL statements.

- For major speed improvements over traditional batch function calls, we developed [batch macros with arguments](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1827) at DosTips. That first macro link develops a number of important concepts. However, the macro form I actually used in the game uses a more [elegant solution with arguments appended](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518).
- A GOTO loop can be replaced by an infinite FOR loop that runs in a new process. You break out of the loop by EXITing the child process.

2) Greatly improve key press detection in a non-blocking way.

- A major limitation of batch is the inability to easily detect a keypress without blocking progress of the game. The problem can be solved by using two processes, both running in the same console window. The controller process reads keypresses and sends them to the main game process via a text file. The controller has multiple modes of operation. The game process sends commands to the controller via another text file. This technique requires careful coordination of input and output redirection.
- The CHOICE command is not available on XP. Some folks at DosTips discovered how to use XCOPY to simulate most of the features of CHOICE, and it works on all versions of Windows. Very cool!

3) Screen painting

- Building the screen character by character is extremely slow. It is much faster to build the initial screen once, using an "array" of strings with fixed length. Each character within a string represents one "pixel". The position within a string represents the X coordinate, and the string row number represents the Y coordinate. Generally, only a few pixels change for any given screen refresh. Pixels can be "plotted" by using SET with simple substring operations. The entire screen can then be quickly refreshed using CLS followed by ECHO of each line in the screen array.

4) Smooth animation

- The amount of work required to perform game logic and screen plotting can vary significantly depending on the current game context. But you want the animation to be smooth. Rather than have a fixed delay between each round of movement, you can instead measure the time since the screen was last updated. Only continue when a pre-determined amount of time has elapsed. As long as all game logic and plotting can occur within the delay time period, then the animation will always be smooth.

Here is pseudo code that describes the timing logic:

```
initialize delayTime
initialize previousTime
loop (
  get currentTime
  set diffTime = currentTime - previousTime
  if diffTime >= delayTime (
    set previousTime = currentTime
    perform user input, game logic, and screen refresh
  )
)
```

And here is actual code that computes the elapsed time since last movement. The currentTime (`t2`) is measured as centiseconds (1/100 second) since midnight. It is parsed and computed using FOR /F and basic math. The diffTime (`tDiff`) will be negative if the previousTime (`t1`) is before midnight and the currentTime (`t2`) is after midnight. If negative, then 1 day is added to diffTime to get the correct time interval.

```
%=== compute time since last move ===%
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!time: =0!") do set /a "t2=(((1%%a*60)+1%%b)*60+1%%c)*100+1%%d-36610100, tDiff=t2-t1"
if !tDiff! lss 0 set /a tDiff+=24*60*60*100
```

There is so much more that can be discussed. Try the SNAKE.BAT game, study the post and the code, and see where your imagination can take you.

Comment: I posted this before I carefully read the comments. I now know the OP already knew about SNAKE.BAT.

Comment: that is fine, i had not understood the game as well before, and i learned more from this post than i did from reading through your code for three hours every night for a week. i had thought that the screen painting was for the snake effect, not optimization. i did wonder: is it better to set a line of enimies at the top, and execute code that changes what is displayed only if there is a hit, or is it better to re display it every time, so that the time for display always take the same amount of time. i guess you hit two birds with one stone. would it be too much to ask for you to explain cont.

Comment: how i could implement a fixed amount of time in my code? i think i can figure the rest out, but i dont quite get that.

Comment: @nephi12 - See my edited answer. If you have additional questions, then I suggest starting a new SO question for each specific programming topic. Your question here is a bit open ended for SO. Another alternative is to join DosTips and start a thread there. The format there is a bit more free form, with lots of back and forth and collaborative brain storming.

Answer (score 5):

Some *optimizations*

1) It's better to use good variable names.

Names like `1`, `2` ... `10` are really bad, nobody knows what they are good for, even you self will not remember in a month.
And then it's also a bad idea as it can have many side effects to use variables begining with digits, in batch there are many where these will simply fail.

2) You should combine your output to complete lines before outputting it.
Then you don't need `set/p` only `echo` and it's faster.

3) calls to functions like `:strlen` should be avoided, calls at all are expensive and in your case it should be possible to solve the same without strlen at all.

4) The function `:checkshot` don't need a for loop.
I don't understand what you try to do there, but you test `slen` if it is a muliple of 5.
This could be solved with

```
set /a remainder=slen %% 5
if !remainder! EQU 0 (
  ...
```

5) Follow the tips of dbenham :-)

Comment: thank you. i like all the ideas except the echo one. i am not quite certain how that would be faster. storing it in a variable then displaying it is faster than displaying it? in any case, that you for your response. i enjoy your having an anser for any problem back on dos tips (not that i have an account, i dont ahve much to add) and i will implement the varibles names, the checkshot idea, the not calling strlen idea, and possibly the echo idea, ill have to test it.

Comment: @nephi12 - jeb is correct. Storing the characters in a string and then displaying the entire string with a single ECHO is significantly faster than using SET /P to incrementally display the line. Try it yourself.

Comment: your right! thank you both for your ideas. hopefully i get them all implemented before the ninth.